# When onActivityResult is ran resultCode is 0 and data is null

Tags: android, android-intent, null, startactivityforresult

I have an activity that sends a boolean array from my inventory class back to my mainGame activity. But when onAcivityResult runs resultCode is 0 and my data is null.

starting the Inventory activity:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public void openInventory(View V) {
        Intent bag = new Intent(MainGame.this, Inventory.class);
        bag.putExtra(booInventory, inventory);
        startActivityForResult(bag, requestItem);
    }
```

ending the Inventory activity:

```
public void onPause(){
        Intent Item = new Intent(Inventory.this, MainGame.class);//data sent to MainGame activity
        Item.putExtra(tools, itemUsed);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, Item);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

onActivityResult: (toaster is a method that creates toast)

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 2){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                toaster("result is ok", 500);
            }

            if(data != null){
                toaster("it worked", 1500);
            }else{
                toaster("FAIL!", 1500);
            }
}
```

Comment: It's a little odd that your `setResult()` call is in `onPause()`... how are you finishing your Inventory activity?

Comment: I'm finishing the inventory activity with onPause() would it work better in onBackPressed().

Comment: Well, you're certainly not calling `finish()` in the `onPause()` implementation posted in your question. How are you closing this activity? Are you just relying on the system to close it for you when you press the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't do that in onPause().

Secondly, replace that

```
Intent Item = new Intent(Inventory.this, MainGame.class)
```

with this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
```

Bonus: Use static variables for the code such as:

```
private static int SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
```

and use that variable inside your methods instead.

Comment: Thank you I just put in the changes you suggested and put the code in  onBackPressed() and it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't recommend you to put that onBackPressed() either. Just use the normal flow and after  setResult(RESULT_OK, Item); call finish();

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers:

The reason your original code didn't work (assuming you were just relying on the system to finish your activity for you when you press the back button) is that **the activity result was already determined by the time `onPause()` executed**.

When you press the back button (again, assuming you haven't changed anything), the system will eventually call `finish()` for you. The source of `Activity.finish()` looks for `mResultCode` and `mResultData`, which are set when you called `setResult()`. It then starts the process of shutting your activity down.

This process will eventually call `onPause()`. But by then, the activity's result has already been determined.

This is why moving your code to `onBackPressed()` works. You're now calling `setResult()` *before* the activity is finished, so `mResultCode` and `mResultData` are what you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

`onPause()` may not be a good place to use setResult. I use to have a button that runs the method I use to set the result. Something like this:

```
public void confirmResults(Item item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("result",item);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Also, please verify that `requestItem = 2` in this line:

`startActivityForResult(bag, requestItem);`